# CTI Dialer in lightning app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, cti

I am looking to add the CTI Dialer that you normally have on a Lightning App's utility bar to a lightning component. Does anyone know if this is possible.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the utility bar and the element that you are expecting on your component?

Comment: Added picture to OP

Comment: So if I understand this, you need an ability on your custom lightning component to render phone numbers enabled as ready to be dialled?

Comment: Pretty much. Just a button that brings up that CTI Softphone application, as you can't have a utility bar in lightning component like lightning app.

Comment: Does the [lightning:clickToDial](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:clickToDial/example) solve your purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Rolling up comments.

You can use [lightning:clickToDial](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:clickToDial/documentation) in your case and integrate it with Open CTI on any custom lightning component.

Excerpt from the documentation:

> Renders a formatted phone number as click-to-dial enabled or disabled for Open CTI and Voice
>
> A `lightning:clickToDial` component respects any existing click-to-dial commands for computer-telephony integrations (CTI) with Salesforce, such as Open CTI and Voice.
>
> The `lightning:clickToDial` component works in conjunction with the Open CTI for Lightning Experience API methods, `enableClickToDial`, `disableClickToDial`, and `onClickToDial`.

Comment: Excatly what I was looking for